# How to call instances by type and most recent date rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have blog post that I want to put on 2 different show views. I want the 4 most recent post to show but all of my post are 1 of 2 different `:post_types` (manager or user). So i want 1 view to show the 4 most recent manager post and the other view to show the 4 most recent user post. Where should I put this logic, the controller or somewhere in the model and how do I make a method to get the 4 most recent post of each type?

Currently i have this in the controller

```
def index

  @blog1 = Post.order(:date => :desc).first 
  @blog2 = Post.order(:date => :desc).offset(1).first
  @blog3 = Post.order(:date => :desc).offset(2).first
  @blog4 = Post.order(:date => :desc).offset(3).first

end
```

But it doesn't separate the post by type

Comment: Is your `Post` model is linked to a `User` model, with something like a `type` attributes? Or are `Manager` and `User` two different models?

Comment: Manager and User are 2 different models. They really are not relevant in this case I dont reference them anywhere with the post. I simply used those types to be able to put the blog post in the proper group for the show views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
def index
  @manager_posts = Post.where(post_type: 'Manager').order('date DESC').limit(4)

  @user_posts    = Post.where(post_type: 'User').order('date DESC').limit(4)
end
```

Then in your view

```
<% @manager_posts.each do |manager_post| %>
  <%= manager_post.content %>
<% end %>

<% @user_posts.each do |user_post| %>
  <%= user_post.content %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: yeah i tried it without the join but it isnt working

Comment: Can you give me your `PostType` model attributes? @SupremeA

Comment: field :post_type, type: String

Comment: And does your `Post` model have a `post_type_id`?

Comment: Yep That got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to get it

```
@blog1 = Post.where(:post_type == 'Manager' ).order(:date => :desc).first
```